# GenericSignatureFormatError in Play! Scala blog example

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm working my way through the [Scala blog engine tutorial](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9/guide1) (yabe) for Play! Framework, and I encountered a template execution error that refers to `GenericSignatureFormatError : null` when accessing comments. Specifically, the error page says:

```
Template execution error
Execution error occured in template /app/views/tags/display.html.
Exception raised was GenericSignatureFormatError : null.

In /app/views/tags/display.html (around line 14)    
 (14)    &nbsp;|&nbsp; ${_arg?.comments.size() ?: 'no'} 
This exception has been logged with id 666i6ifgg
```

The stack trace from the console is below. I can reproduce the problem within `samples-and-tests/` from the github master ([43b195](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/commit/43b19540a047082093a1eab81bad97c0d791ad52)), as follows:

```
% git clone https://github.com/playframework/play-scala.git
% cd play-scala/samples-and-tests/yabe
% play dependencies
~ play! 1.2, http://www.playframework.org
~ Resolving dependencies using /home/league/tmp/play-scala/samples-and-tests/yabe/conf/dependencies.yml,
~   play->scala 0.9 (from playLocalModules)
~ Installing resolved dependencies,
~   modules/scala-0.9 -> /usr/local/stow/play-1.2/share/play-1.2/modules/scala-0.9
~   lib/joda-time-1.6.jar
~ Done!
% play run
~ play! 1.2, http://www.playframework.org
~ Warning: conflict on command scala:console
~ Ctrl+C to stop
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
10:32:01,076 INFO  ~ Starting /home/league/tmp/play-scala/samples-and-tests/yabe
10:32:01,079 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.scala)
10:32:01,080 INFO  ~ Module scala is available (/home/league/tmp/play-scala/samples-and-tests/yabe/../..)
10:32:01,080 INFO  ~ Module scala is available (/usr/local/stow/play-1.2/share/play-1.2/modules/scala-0.9)
10:32:02,515 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
10:32:02,591 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
```

Then, loading http://localhost:9000/ produces the error stated above, with this console output:

```
@666i6ifgg
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /

Template execution error (In /app/views/tags/display.html around line 14)
Execution error occured in template /app/views/tags/display.html. Exception raised was GenericSignatureFormatError : null.

play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:84)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:236)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:346)
    at /app/views/Application/index.html.(line:6)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:213)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:657)
    at play.mvc.ControllerDelegate.renderTemplateForScala(ControllerDelegate.java:46)
    at play.mvc.results.Template.<init>(Template.scala:12)
    at play.mvc.ScalaController.Template(ScalaController.scala:77)
    at controllers.Application$.index(app/controllers.scala:27)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:540)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:498)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:492)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:469)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:157)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:385)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:116)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:74)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:58)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1196)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:423)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:189)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:250)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:404)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at /app/views/tags/display.html.(line:14)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:213)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: The issue seems to be List objects in the template. Something like `${posts}` will print the List with toString but these fail: `${posts[0]}` or `${posts.size()}` or `#{if posts}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around this problem by switching to the Sun JDK. I didn't realize that my Ubuntu was set to use OpenJDK instead. The [installation guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/install) claims that either one should work. Perhaps that is untrue, or perhaps I got unlucky with a particular bug related to this version of OpenJDK.

For anyone else having this problem, `update-java-alternatives -l` shows the available JDKs; I see:

```
java-6-openjdk 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
java-6-sun 63 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

These come from the Ubuntu packages

```
sun-java6-bin          6.24-1build0.10.10.1
openjdk-6-jre-headless 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1
```

Use this to select:

```
update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
${_arg?.comments.size() ?: 'no'}
```

to

```
${(_arg?.comments.size() > 0) ? '': 'no'}
```

This should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It seems to be a deeper/internal issue. If I comment out that line, the next occurrence of `_arg?.comments` triggers same error. And if I remove them all, it occurs in another template on the code `#{if older}`

Comment: Sure, it's just the templates from the demo included with the distribution, here: https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/tree/master/samples-and-tests/yabe/app/views . So it crashes in `tags/display.html` which is called from `Application/index.html`.